# Ошибка в парсинге json, kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.lang.NumberFormatException
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val cur = arrayOf(
        "CAD", "HKD", "ISK", "PHP", "DKK", "HUF", "CZK", "GBP", "RON", "SEK", "IDR", "INR", "BRL", "RUB", "HRK", "JPY",
        "THB", "CHF", "EUR", "MYR", "BGN", "TRY", "CNY", "NOK", "NZD", "ZAR", "USD", "MXN", "SGD", "AUD", "ILS", "KRW", "PLN"
    )
    val URL = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base="

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val spinAdapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cur)
        to_cur.adapter = spinAdapt
        from_cur.adapter = spinAdapt

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            loadServerData()
        }
    }

    private fun loadServerData() {
        var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
        var currency: String
        val request: Request = Request.Builder().url("${URL}${to_cur.selectedItem}").build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Server connection error, please reconnect to the Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                try {
                    val resp = response?.body?.toString()
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                    val cur = gson.fromJson(resp, JSONCURR::class.java)
                    runOnUiThread{et_to.text = cur.rates.find{it.containsKey(to_cur.selectedItem)}.toString()}
                } catch(e: NullPointerException) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Server connection error, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        })
    }
}

class JSONCURR(val rates: Array<Map<String, Double>>)
```

Пытаюсь получить распарсить json, но выдается ошибка:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: Эта ошибка - классика жанра

Comment: Вам приходит ОБЬЕКТ который содержит в себе данные а вы пытаетесь полуить  массив. Массива в вашем ответе нет

Answer (score 1):

вместо

```
val resp = response?.body?.toString()
```

необходимо было написать

```
val resp = response?.body?.string()
```

Comment: Если дополните почему, будет полноценный ответ. Иначе непонятно почему вопрос по JSON превратился в ответ по Retrofit.